# ERPNEXT bench get-app payments no such file or directory issue

Tags: erpnext, frappe

I'm installing ERPNEXT 14 on VirtualBox using instructions from https://github.com/D-codE-Hub/Frappe-ERPNext-Version-14--in-Ubuntu-22.04-LTS. I encountered an error during

bench get-app payments

saying
fatal: repository 'payments' does not exist
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'home/kim/frappe-bench/apps/payments/setup.py'

How do I resolve this? Thanks!

[screenshot01](https://i.stack.imgur.com/081rL.png)

[screenshot02](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SjpdS.png)

I already tried reinstalling with a new Virtual Machine. same result.

Answer (score 1):

update Your bench version `pip3 install --upgrade frappe-bench`